# Join different tables based on column condition

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements

I have the following tables:

```
Transaction (Transaction_Date, Location, Type, Cust_id) - Type can be 'W' or 'S'
Store_Cust (ID, Name, Mobile)
Web_Cust (ID, Name, Mobile)
```

I am querying the table `Transaction` and I need to join based on the `Type` column

If `Type` column is  'W', I need to join with `Web_Cust` to get `Name` and `Mobile`
If `Type` column is 'S', I need to join with `Store_Cust` to get `Name` and `Mobile`

How to do the conditional join on tables?

Answer (score 0):

You could just do left joins to the 2 customer tables, and then retain the appropriate fields based on type, using a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT
    t.Transaction_Date, t.Location, t.Type, t.Cust_id,
    CASE WHEN t.Type = 'S' THEN s.Name ELSE w.Name END AS Name,
    CASE WHEN t.Type = 'S' THEN s.Mobile ELSE w.Mobile END AS Mobile
FROM "Transaction" t
LEFT JOIN Store_Cust s
    ON s.ID = t.Cust_id
LEFT JOIN Web_Cust w
    ON w.ID = t.Cust_id;
```

Note that your current database design is probably sub-optimal, and the store and web customer tables should probably be a single table with a type column to discriminate between the two types of customers.  Also note that `TRANSACTION` is a reserved Oracle keyword, and you should avoid naming your tables using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do conditional joins but you can do what you want in a couple of ways.   Assuming you want the the and mobile to return in the same column in your query (if you want the in separate columns it is even easier)

## Outer Join

```
select t.*, case t.type when 'W' then w.name when 'S' then s.name else 'Error' end as name,
       case t.type when 'W' then w.mobile when 'S' then s.mobile else 'Error' end as mobile
from   transaction t
  left outer join web_cust w on t.cust_id = w.cust_id and t.type = 'W'
  left outer join store_cust s on t.cust_id = s.cust_id and t.type = 'S'
```

This query will return the associated rows from `web_cust` and `store_cust` with the values from the *other* table being null

| t.type | w.name | s.name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| W | Cust 1 | null |
| S | null | Cust2 |

## Union

```
select t.*, w.name, w.mobile
from   transaction t
  join web_cust w on t.cust_id = w.cust_id
where  t.type = 'W'
UNION ALL
select t.*, s.name, s.mobile
from   transaction t
  join store_cust s on t.cust_id = s.cust_id
where  t.type = 'S'
```

This just runs two separate queries and joins the results together into one dataset.

## Notes

Which is the best option depends on the data volumes and database structure.

All this said, the best solution is to rework the database.   This setup means you cannot have a foreign key between your transaction and customer table(s)

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT` joins of `Transaction` to `Store_Cust` and `Web_Cust` and set the conditions about the type in the `ON` clauses.
Then use `COALESCE()` to get the proper name and mobile:

```
SELECT t.*,
    COALESCE(s.Name, w.Name) Name,
    COALESCE(s.Mobile, w.Mobile) Mobile
FROM "Transaction" t
LEFT JOIN Store_Cust s ON s.ID = t.Cust_id AND t.Type = 'S'
LEFT JOIN Web_Cust w ON w.ID = t.Cust_id AND t.Type = 'W';
```